# USPS shipping calculator API not returning valid response

Tags: php, api, usps

I am getting this error from USPS
I am making query at http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=RateV4&XML=

```xml
<Error>
    <Number>80040b1a</Number>
    <Description>Authorization failure.  You are not authorized to connect to this server.</Description>
    <Source>UspsCom::DoAuth</Source>
</Error>
```

And if I am making the same query at test server http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPItest.dll?API=RateV4&XML= it's getting me the following error

```xml
<Error>
    <Number>80040b1a</Number>
    <Description>API Authorization failure. RateV4 is not a valid API name for this protocol.</Description>
    <Source>UspsCom::DoAuth</Source>
</Error>
```

Comment: Did you register with USPS Web Tools?

Comment: @peterm Yes indeed. If i make a query at the test server it give me error like "RateV4 is not a valid API name for this protocol"

Comment: In both cases it tells you `Authorization failure`. Do you supply correct XML in your URL after `...XML=` including USER ID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ravish- RateV4 is not applicable in Testing server, therefore you won't be able to obtain any response. And, in regards to RateV4 in Production server, you will need to obtain permission from ICCC, USPS. Hope it helps.

Comment: So if RateV4 isn't applicable as you say, what SHOULD be posted to get testing to work correctly?